# apt upgrade leads to man-db segmentation fault and broken system

Tags: 16.04, dpkg, segmentation-fault

When upgrading my 16.04 server (due to Intel CPU bugs) via "apt upgrade" the installation stopped saying this:

```
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
dpkg: error processing package man-db (--unpack):
 subprocess installed post-installation script was killed by signal (Segmentation fault)
dpkg: error: error executing hook 'if { test "$DPKG_HOOK_ACTION" = add-architecture || test "$DPKG_HOOK_ACTION" = remove-architecture; } && test -x /usr/share/pkg-config-dpkghook; then /usr/share/pkg-config-dpkghook update; fi', exit code 11
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Afterwards everything I did on the command line gave me "Segmentation fault". I had to do a hardware reset, but the data center guys say it won't boot and activated a rescue system for me. Now I have access to the filesystem and don't have a clue what to do to make it boot again.

Any hints?

Last lines of dpkg.log:

```
2018-01-10 08:46:14 trigproc libc-bin:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu9 <none>
2018-01-10 08:46:14 status half-configured libc-bin:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu9
2018-01-10 08:46:15 status installed libc-bin:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu9
2018-01-10 08:46:15 trigproc man-db:amd64 2.7.5-1 <none>
2018-01-10 08:46:15 status half-configured man-db:amd64 2.7.5-1
```

syslog:

```
Jan 10 08:46:15 lab2 kernel: [494064.841594] man-db.postinst[22513]: segfault at 0 ip           (null) sp 00007fff8334bdc8 error 14 in dash[55e693270000+24000
]
Jan 10 08:46:15 lab2 kernel: [494065.059746] sh[22514]: segfault at 0 ip           (null) sp 00007ffff90ad888 error 14 in dash[55cdfb522000+24000]
Jan 10 08:46:15 lab2 kernel: [494065.063890] dpkg[22515]: segfault at 0 ip           (null) sp 00007ffd67ad2a88 error 14 in dpkg[400000+43000]
Jan 10 08:46:15 lab2 kernel: [494065.064688] dpkg[22516]: segfault at 0 ip           (null) sp 00007ffeb6255a08 error 14 in dpkg[400000+43000]
Jan 10 08:46:16 lab2 kernel: [494066.318327] dpkg[22517]: segfault at 0 ip           (null) sp 00007ffc52ee34c8 error 14 in dpkg[400000+43000]
Jan 10 08:46:26 lab2 kernel: [494075.929883] modprobe[22518]: segfault at 0 ip           (null) sp 00007ffef301a178 error 14 in kmod[5626c191b000+23000]
Jan 10 08:46:26 lab2 kernel: [494075.930180] modprobe[22519]: segfault at 0 ip           (null) sp 00007ffdffa7a448 error 14 in kmod[561e4330a000+23000]
Jan 10 08:46:26 lab2 kernel: [494075.930438] modprobe[22520]: segfault at 0 ip           (null) sp 00007ffec57393e8 error 14 in kmod[55c3795ee000+23000]
Jan 10 08:46:26 lab2 kernel: [494075.930681] modprobe[22521]: segfault at 0 ip           (null) sp 00007ffca4907e38 error 14 in kmod[55f719d07000+23000]
Jan 10 08:46:26 lab2 kernel: [494075.930904] modprobe[22522]: segfault at 0 ip           (null) sp 00007ffe31ba44a8 error 14 in kmod[55a8cb885000+23000]
Jan 10 08:46:54 lab2 kernel: [494104.429399] apt[22523]: segfault at 0 ip           (null) sp 00007ffe571311d8 error 14 in apt[558747816000+3000]
```

Comment: What exact kernel do you have? According to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1741934/comments/52, issues should be fixed in 4.4.0-109.132.

Comment: I have 4.4.0-104 and the upgrade wanted to install 4.4.0-108, but did not finish obviously. My system seems to be seriously corrupted, it does not matter which kernel I choose (via symlinks in root dir).